# LINQ vs Lambda vs Anonymous Methods vs Delegates

Tags: c#, linq, delegates, lambda, anonymous-methods

1. Can anyone explain what are the LINQ, Lambda, Anonymous Methods, Delegates meant?
2. How these 3 are different for each other?
3. Was one replaceable for another?

I didn't get any concrete answer when i did Googling

Comment: there are 4 things in that list...

Comment: @Sri Kumar: I didn't down vote but I would guess it is a mix between the fact that this is readily available information and that your English is not perfect.

Comment: Sometimes it IS readily available, however SO in it's very nature is supposed to be a repository of information so that it's users don't always have to go elsewhere.  Jeff Atwood said himself an answer that is simply a link is NOT helpful, but a copy and paste of information FROM that link IS helpful.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

LINQ is a broad technology name covering a large chunk of .NET 3.5 and the C# 3.0 changes;  "query in the language" and tons more.

A delegate is comparable to a function-pointer; a "method handle" as an object, if you like, i.e.

```
Func<int,int,int> add = (a,b) => a+b;
```

is *a* way of writing a delegate that I can then call. Delegates also underpin eventing and other callback approaches.

Anonymous methods are the 2.0 short-hand for creating delegate instances, for example:

```
someObj.SomeEvent += delegate {
    DoSomething();
};
```

they also introduced full closures into the language via "captured variables" (not shown above). C# 3.0 introduces lambdas, which *can* produce the same as anonymous methods:

```
someObj.SomeEvent += (s,a) => DoSomething();
```

but which can **also** be compiled into expression trees for full LINQ against (for example) a database. You can't run a delegate against SQL Server, for example! but:

```
IQueryable<MyData> source = ...
var filtered = source.Where(row => row.Name == "fred");
```

*can* be translated into SQL, as it is compiled into an expression tree (`System.Linq.Expression`).

So:

- an anonymous method can be used to create a delegate
- a lambda *might* be the same as an anon-method, but not necessarily