# Minimum Spanning Tree quick graph

Tags: c#, minimum-spanning-tree, quickgraph

I want to find the minimum spanning tree of the following graph using quick graph. I Went through the manual provided but I don't really understand how to do it.
Here is my code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        var g = new UndirectedGraph<int, TaggedUndirectedEdge<int,int>>();

        var e1 = new TaggedUndirectedEdge<int, int>(1, 2, 57);
        var e2 = new TaggedUndirectedEdge<int, int>(1, 4, 65);
        var e3 = new TaggedUndirectedEdge<int, int>(2, 3, 500);
        var e4 = new TaggedUndirectedEdge<int, int>(2, 4, 1);
        var e5 = new TaggedUndirectedEdge<int, int>(3, 4, 78);
        var e6 = new TaggedUndirectedEdge<int, int>(3, 5, 200);

        g.AddVerticesAndEdge(e1);
        g.AddVerticesAndEdge(e2);
        g.AddVerticesAndEdge(e3);
        g.AddVerticesAndEdge(e4);
        g.AddVerticesAndEdge(e5);
        g.AddVerticesAndEdge(e6);

        foreach (var v in g.Edges)
            Console.WriteLine(v);
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you read http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Minimum%20Spanning%20Tree

Comment: Yes I did but i was kind of lost when i read this line:"Func<TEdge, double> edgeWeights = ...;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@daryal beat me to it - my version is:

```
var mst = g.MinimumSpanningTreePrim(e => e.Tag).ToList();
```

[image]

*"Use the source Luke"* - I looked at MinimumSpanningTreeTest.cs, test Prim12273

(Also you could look at this question on [Lambda's / Delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652264/linq-vs-lambda-vs-anonymous-methods-vs-delegates) for a better understanding of basic function pointers)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `Tag` (last) parameter of `TaggedUndirectedEdge` implies the edgeWeight of the edge, the following may work.

```
Func<TEdge, double> edgeWeights = (q) => {
g.Edges.SingleOrDefault(m => q == m).Tag;
}

IEnumerable<TEdge> mst = g.MinimumSpanningTreePrim(g, edgeWeights);
```